# Can Someone Explain what is happening on line 4. I mean how the value of 'now' is getting updated?

Tags: python, greedy

this is the code a question which uses greedy approach, can someone help what is happening at line 5 i.e., how the value of 'now' getting updated?

```
def calculate():
    arr=[30, 15, 60, 75, 45, 15, 15, 45]
    last,now=0,0
    for i in arr:
        last,now=now,max(last+i,now)
    return now
```

Comment: `now=max(last+i,now)` that's how is being updated. But why are you writing two assignments in one line?

Comment: why in 2nd iteration the value of 'now' is 30 not 45?

Comment: It's a clever way to essentially swap two values.  The right side becomes a tuple, and when you assign a tuple to a comma-separated set of names like that, the tuple is unwound.  So it's the same as `last=now` and `now=max(last+i,now)`, except you don't have to worry about storing one of them in a temporary.

Comment: After the first iteration, last=0 and now=30.  In the second iteration, last+i is 15, so it isn't larger than the current version of now.  last becomes 30, now stays at 30.

Comment: If you can get why `a,b,c,d = 1,2,3,4` works, then you should be able to get that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is basically the same as:

```
temp = last
last = now
now = max(temp+i, now)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: Yes, it should just be `temp = last`.  The tuple trick lets you avoid creating a temporary like this.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Thanks Thierry and Tim for pointing it out. I just corrected it.